# When installing a VM, is there a difference between installing it in a separate partition on the same hard disk?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using Virtual Box to install some VMs on my laptop.

My laptop has a single hard disk that has been partitioned into two, the first partition containing the C: drive and the second partition is currently empty.

I am wondering if there is any difference if I install the VM onto the first partition or the second partition?

I am looking at this from the point of view of impact on the performance of the VM and host and the longevity of the hard disk (my hard disk recently crash, and the laptop is less than a year old)

Thank you in advance for any input provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets do some background first:

1. You can install a VM with a **virtual disk** stored on a volume on the host OS.
2. You can install a VM with a **real disk/partition backing it**.

The most used way is to install an OS on the laptop disk (e.g. partition the disk, create two volumes. Usually C:\ and D:. Then the host OS gets installed to C: and D: gets used for storage (e.g. movies, your documents, VM images, ...).

If this is also the case with your laptop then you should just stores the virtual disk on D: to keep things simple and clean.

---

OK, so far for the most common situation. Now some more background.

A rotating disk at a fixed RPM has more disk surface pass below the Read/write had per second on the outside than on the inside. This is easy to see if you mentally rotate the disk in the picture below. If you keep your finger (or the R/W head) near the green ring then more surface will pass your finger in one rotation than if you rotate it with your finger near the red line.

[image]

This more passing surface means more passing information to read (faster) or write (faster). That makes the outer tracks of your disk faster.

> I am wondering if there is any difference if I install the VM onto the first partition or the second partition?

So yes, there could be a difference.

However you did not post if partition 1 was near the outside of the disk and partition 2 was near the inside. Or vice versa. Nor do all disks work the same. 
Most disk come with multiple platters and R/W heads at both side of the disk. And there are multiple ways to allocate sectors. Some simply start at the inside off all platters and move outwards. Some may start at the outside and move inward (which means for some sector #1 might be fastest and for other the highest sector may be fastest). Then there are at least a few disks which use platter for platter, creating a saw-tooth performance curve.

And without that information on your disk and how your partitioned the disk there is no way to answer your question except with a 'Yes, maybe'.

Comment: This might be true for 1 platter disk and big un-fragmented files, but VM are more about random access. So no real measurable impact on performance.

Comment: Agreed. I expect the difference to be negligible and the OP should just put the files on D:\..  I also half expected him to try RAW disk access. Possibly to the same partition as his main OS. Which could be bad.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, not much (if any) **direct** impact on performance.

VM disk access are not about reading big files, but are more about random accessing their big disk file(s). In that case, the partition geometry impact, as explained by Hennes, is usually not that obvious.

The best way here would have been to add another disk unit as: `more disk = more IO`, but this is not really possible on a laptop.

Still, having the VM files on their own private place might limit the fragmentation. This will have little impact on the short terms, but might have a positive impact on the long terms performance.

To conclude: you can do it, but the gain will be more about organisation, not performance.